# Android Studio Surface View con botones

Tags: android, android-studio, botón

tengo un sprite que se mueve cuando el booleano es true y se detiene cuando es false. Esto lo quiero activar con un boton que tengo en el Main activity. El problema es que cuando lo presiono la aplicación se detiene.

Que estoy haciendo mal? Cual seria la mejor forma de hacer esto?

Gracias.

Main Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1;
    private Sprite sprite;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    }

    public void play(View view){
        sprite.playing = true;
    }
}
```

Juego:

```
    public class Juego extends SurfaceView {

    private Bitmap personaje;
    private Sprite sprite;

    public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        personaje = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bad1);
        sprite = new Sprite(this, personaje);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Sprite:

```
    private static final int Horizontal = 4;
    private static final int Vertical = 3;
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private Juego juego;
    private Bitmap personaje;
    private int currentFrame = 0;
    private int ancho;
    private int alto;

    long fps;
    private long timeThisFrame;
    private long lastFrameChangeTime = 0;
    private int frameLengthInMilliseconds = 100;
    int cantFrames = 3;
    boolean playing = false;

    public Sprite(Juego juego, Bitmap personaje){
        this.juego = juego;
        this.personaje = personaje;
        this.ancho = personaje.getWidth() / Vertical;
        this.alto = personaje.getHeight() / Horizontal;
    }

    private void update() {

        if (playing) {

            long startFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (startFrame > lastFrameChangeTime + frameLengthInMilliseconds) {
                lastFrameChangeTime = startFrame;
                currentFrame++;
                if (currentFrame >= cantFrames) {

                    currentFrame = 0;
                }
            }

            long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
            if (timeThisFrame >= 1) {
                fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        update();
        int srcX = currentFrame * ancho;
        int srcY = alto;
        Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + ancho, srcY + alto);
        Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + ancho, y + alto);
        canvas.drawBitmap(personaje, src, dst, null);
    }
}
```

xlm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light">


<com.example.agusv.movertipito.Juego
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
android:id="@+id/customView"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="play"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
07-19 21:20:00.089 18824-18824/com.example.agusv.movertipito E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.agusv.movertipito, PID: 18824
                                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.agusv.movertipito.Sprite.mover()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.agusv.movertipito.MainActivity.play(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Si agregas tu mensaje desplaegado en LogCat, sería de mucha utilidad

Comment: agrega activity_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando el código de tu `MainActivity`:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1;
    private Sprite sprite;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    }

    public void play(View view){
        sprite.playing = true;
    }
}
```

puedo determinar 2 situaciones:

El botón `b1` no tiene asignado un listener, por lo tanto cuando das click y esta realizando una acción lo esta realizando mediante el llamado del método por la propiedad `android:OnClick` que debes tener en tu layout `activity_main.xml`, el método que estas llamando es :

```
public void play(View view){
            sprite.playing = true;
        }
```

y el problema es que `sprite` es una variable que no esta inicializada y tiene un valor null, debes inicializar la variable para resolver tu problema.

---

Actualización:

gracias por agregar tu mensaje en el LogCat, en realidad es el problema que comentaba:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void com.example.agusv.movertipito.Sprite.mover()' on a null
>   object reference

---

¿Como puedes inicializar la variable sprite? esto lo puedes ver en la clase Juego:

```
private Bitmap personaje;
 private Sprite sprite;

 public void play(View view){

        personaje = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bad1);
        sprite = new Sprite(this, personaje);

        sprite.playing = true;

    }
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Como puedo inicializar la variable Sprite?  Estuve intentando pero no me sale. Ahora subo el xml y el LogCat

Comment: Era lo que comentaba, revisa la actualización.

Comment: Lo hice pero me tira error en esta parte sprite = new Sprite("this, personaje"); Dice: Sprite
(com.example.agusv.movertipito.Juego,
Bitmap)
in Sprite cannot be applied
to
(com.example.agusv.movertipito.MainActivity,
Bitmap)

Comment: en lugar de this, debe ser el surfaceView, de donde obtuviste este ejemplo???